# Vue.js - Fetch Data from API and reload component on Vuex state change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I come from jQuery background and just recently started using Vue. I'm trying to learn as much as I can and I'm trying to develop a simple user search and view details app however I am getting stuck and can't seem to find a way out to proceed forward.

[image]

I've a layout of three components - Nav.vue, Search.vue, UserProfile.vue as in the picture. UserProfile.vue is inside router view. I'm using Vuex store with states userId and username and I've defined mutations to commit the state changes.

When user searches by providing username in Search component I'm fetching users list from API on left sidebar. When user clicks on one of the search result I'm committing userId state and looking to fetch from API and display the user profile on the UserProfile component using the userId retrieved from Vuex store. The UserProfile component is inside router view.

### Vuex store.js:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({

state: {
    userId:"",
    username: ""
}

mutations: {

  setUserId (state, payload) {
    state.userId = payload
  },

  setUsername (state, payload) {
    state.user.username = payload
  },
}

});
```

### On Search.vue

```
Search.vue (outside  <router-view />)
-------------------------------------
<a href="#" @click="viewProfile" class="btn btn-info" >View Profile</a>

methods: {

    viewProfile() {
        this.$store.commit("setUserId", this.userId);
        this.$store.commit("setUsername", this.username);
    }
}
```

### On UserProfile.vue

I'm getting userId from state from a computed property.

```
UserProfile.vue (inside  <router-view />)
-------------------------------------------

computed: {
    userId () {
      return this.$store.state.userId
    }
  }
```

Now I want to fetch data from API and display the data in UserProfile component based on the selected userId which I'm retrieving from Vuex store but I'm stuck. Any pointer would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what parts are done? Have you done the search? If so then do @click="viewProfile(item)", in viewProfile use a HTTP client like axios, to get the user, but you have them details already so just set it, ideally you want to aim for namespace stores, and like this.$store.commit("user/set", item);, then set it into this.$store.state.user. then it will save adding mutators for every user property which can quickly fill out, also look into mapState, it will reduce `this.$store.state.user.username` into `this.user.username` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do.

in `viewProfile` method, after mutating `userId` and `username`, I would fetch data from API. Actually, I use Vuex `action` and `setUserId`, `setUsername` mutations would be inside Vuex action.
Parameters to API call will be `userId` and we need to save response(profile data) which can be in Vuex or in the component.

I say we don't need to change url when we select a user from searched users' results. `UserProfile` component would just render response data.

If we are supposed to go to other pages like `localhost://users/:id`, then we have to use a `mounted` hook.
`mounted` hook is where we have to call fetch function to get profile data based on router parameter `id`.

Comment: In addition to your answer, I followed this Vuex Crash Course tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lVQgZzLMHc by Traversy Media to understand the flow fully.

Answer (score 0):

Your store should contain state, getters, mutations and actions.
Getters are used to retrieve the state.
Mutations are used to updated the state. (mutations should be used only from actions)
Actions are used to commit mutations.

Also in actions you can fetch data from your Api.
To use actions you can use the syntax:
$store.dispach("action-name",payload) the payload is optional.

For more documentation regarding vuex please visit :
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions